# Is every 13th wave larger then the rest?

Tags: physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the ninth wave the largest?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/is-the-ninth-wave-the-largest)

In the movie Kon-Tiki, the crew relies crucially on the claim that every 13th wave (over a reef) is larger then the rest, I have heard before that every 7th is the largest (at the coast), is there any truth to these statements?
I imagine someone somewhere must have carried out this elementary experiment.

Comment: I am looking for a reference from someone who has actually measured the amplitude of ocean waves.

Comment: That answer in the linked question is really silly and useless because it relies on some complicated theory, it should be tested experimentally.

Comment: @smoke: You should take that observation over to that question then.

Comment: @smoke: It was tested experimentally. *"To obtain a spectrum of a fully developed sea, they used measurements of waves made by accelerometers on British weather ships in the North Atlantic"* - [Ocean Wave Spectra](http://oceanworld.tamu.edu/resources/ocng_textbook/chapter16/chapter16_04.htm) where "they" is Pierson & Moskowitz, the people mentioned in the paper in the first link of the answer you refer to (e.g. Figure 4).